# What will the GCC pre-processor look to optimize?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Let's say we have a macro + a function:

```
#define MY_MACRO (2*64)

int foo(void)
{
    return (2 * (MY_MACRO));
}
```

Will gcc optimize `MY_MACRO` to equal 128 at compile-time instead of making the calculation a run-time operation? And taking it one step further, within the return statement, will it optimize this to equal 256 in a similar fashion?

If so, what other things will the pre-processor look for in regards to possible optimizations?

Comment: The optimizer doesn't even see the macros. It's a totally different level

Comment: [Even with -O0](https://godbolt.org/g/73tBYR)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: yep, but the question remains for `return 2 * (2*64);`

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question as it stands: *what other things will the pre-processor look for in regards to possible optimizations* - doesn't make sense at all, as preprocessors don't do any optimizations. What the OP is looking for is *constant expressions*.

Comment: @EugeneSh.:the questions "Will gcc optimize MY_MACRO to equal 128 at compile-time instead of making the calculation a run-time operation?" and "And taking it one step further, within the return statement, will it optimize this to equal 256 in a similar fashion?" remain. *gcc* is not the preprocessor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are free to interpret the question as you like :) But since you are answering, please correct the terminological errors as well, otherwise the OP will continue to imagine the things in the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

> What will the GCC pre-processor look to optimize?

Nothing. The preprocessor doesn't perform optimizations -- all it does is expand macros and `#include` directives.

However, once the preprocessor is done with your code, all the compiler sees is:

```
return (2 * ((2*64)));
```

which it can certainly optimize to the equivalent of `return 256`. It neither knows nor cares that the input `(2*64)` was generated by a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the optimizer (not the preprocessor) should merge the constants.

With aggressive optimization it might even inline the whole function as the int constant 256.

Answer (score 0):

Constant values are normally [evaluated at compile time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) by gcc, so yes.

The preprocessor just replaces text though, optimization is done by the compiler.

Which optimizations are performed, depends on the compiler, the optimization level, the CPU architecture you target, and many other decision the compiler developers have taken.

If you need to know, you should inspect the assembly code generated by the compiler yourself, e.g. run

```
gcc -O2 -S foo.c
```

And inspect the generated `foo.s` file. Here is an example for an ARM platform, as you can see no multiplication is being performed:

```
foo:

        mov     r0, #256
        bx      lr
```